# Best way to save/load 4-dimensional array in Octave

Tags: csv, load, octave

I have an Octave code that gathers data from thousands of .csv files and stores it in a 4-dimensional matrix (800x8x80x213) so I can access it with other code. The process of reading in the data takes about 10 minutes so I thought it would be a good idea to save the matrix and then I could load it into the workspace whenever I wanted to work with the data instead of waiting 10 minutes for the matrix to be created. I used `Save` to save the matrix and `Load` to load it into the workspace, however when I loaded the matrix, it took 30 minutes to complete. Is there a better/faster way to save/load this 4-D matrix? Seems ridiculous that it takes 3 times longer to load a matrix than to create it from 4000+ files...

Comment: When you save a file you can choose different file formats. Which format did you choose? Also, maybe when you read the 4000+ files the files were memory cache, while the file with the final matrix was not.

Comment: For the record: on my PC with 12 cores & 16GB RAM / Win10 :
Saving a 800x8x80x213 arrays of doubles in -hdf5 format with Octave 6.4 takes around 4.3 s, and reloading it takes around 0.25 s. I get similar performances with Scilab 6.1: 2.5 s to save, and 0.23 to load
So, either your array is not of doubles, or you do not use the most relevant data format (as carandraug suggested), or your PC does not have enough RAM and then swaps with a physical disk.

Comment: @S.Gougeon Looks like the format was the issue as I was saving as a text. Switching to binary sped things up tremendously, with less than a second to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default 'format' option used by the `save` command is `-text`, which is human readable. For large datasets, this will take a long time to create (not to mention, it will lead to a much larger file, since it will need to represent floating point numbers via their text representations...), so it is indeed inappropriate for this kind of data. Loading from a large text format file will also take quite a long time, especially on a slow computer, for the same reasons.

Octave also supports a `-binary` option, which is octave's internal binary format. This is what you need. E.g.

```
save -binary outputfile.bin varname
```

In this particular case, the text file is 2.2G, whereas the binary format is the expected 872Mb (i.e. number of elements * 8 bytes per element). Saving and loading is near instant.

Alternatively, there's a bunch of other options too, corresponding to other common formats, e.g. as a commenter has also mentioned here, `-hdf5`, or `-v7` which is matlab's .mat format.

Type `help save` on your octave console for more details.